# FirebaseAuth isSuccessful and result properties don´t exist

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, authentication, firebase-authentication

```
private fun setup() {
    title = "Autenticación"
    RegisterButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (editTextTextEmailAddress.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()) {
           FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextTextEmailAddress.text.toString(), editTextTextPassword.text.toString())
            if (it.isSuccessfull) {

            } else {
                ShowAlert()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that's my code, and I didn´t found anything more on the internet.

Comment: please, explain why that is not working, provide the community with the error you are getting. The more you can explain your problem the most you will get from the community. To a quick question, you will never have a smart answer.

Comment: +1. I agree, the only reason I saw your problem was because I read through the code and when people are helping you, its best to make it as easy and understandable as possible. Always mention your problem, show relevant code, elaborate on libraries etc being used, and of course show or explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I suspect this is what you want to do

```
if (editTextTextEmailAddress.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()) {
    FirebaseAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextTextEmailAddress.text.toString(), editTextTextPassword.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Yay we were successful
                } else {
                    // Oh no something went wrong
                }
            }
}
```

Always refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#kotlin+ktx_1) in cases where you are confused.

Essentially when you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` you need to add a `OnCompleteListener` as the authentication is done asynchronously in the background, and within the `OnCompleteListener` you can then carry on with your logic based on success or failure of the authentication.